# Where's the safety bug in this double comparison

Tags: java, bug-tracking

I was interviewed yesterday and this question arise:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Code fragment must prints true if the double variables x and y are both
        // strictly between 0 and 1 and false otherwise. 

        // Assuming args will be always correct (double) input, 
        // Where's the safety bug?

        double x,y;

        x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

        System.out.println( (0 < x && x < 1) && (0 < y && y < 1)? true : false );
    }
}
```

I wrote there were no bug anywhere, I mean, code works. Back at home, tried and indeed it works. But although I did get the job, this question was my only bad one, and I can't get it out of my head (it seams fair straight simple). I believe I don't even understand what a safety bug is so, my question then is:

What's a safety bug and does this code indeed have one?

**UPDATE:**

After response I put some related resources:

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)'s [Why does JScript have rounding errors?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/why-does-jscript-have-rounding-errors.aspx)

Comment: Since you got the job, why can't you just ask your interviewer?

Comment: Part of the problem is the ambiguity of this question. What kind of safety are we talking about? Thread safety? Type safety? Security?

Comment: @MattBall didn't said. Others candidates were being asked during the afternoon.

Comment: @Jeremy I honestly don't. I'm not an expert on the field, but seing Durandal response I guess it could be type safety!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the comment in the source:

> Assuming args will be always correct (double) input, Where's the safety bug?

There exists a case in which the program will deliver a wrong output, and there seems to be no dubious except the expression itself:

> (0 < x && x < 1) && (0 < y && y < 1)

Although I haven't tested it, there may be a problem when this expression is confronted with one of the edge cases for either x or y: NaN, +/- infinity and maybe even -0.0.

Also there exist definitively valid inputs which may violate the logical expectation of the user due to the limited precision with which number are represented in a double (e.g. x = 1E-400 is greater than 0, but parses as 0, so the expression delivers false although the user would expect true).

Comment: +1 I've tested with 0.1 0.9999999999999999999999 and the response is false. Pretty weird (for me, I'm obviously not an expert). I'm starting to believe it's all about type safety as @Jeremy suggested also. The thing is, how to prevent that precision problem. Only by cropping or limiting input or there's another way?

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul Floating-point numbers are just approximations of the real numbers known from mathematics. Humans are used to dealing with decimal approximations of numbers but due to the architecture of computers we use, fp numbers use binary approximations, which do not always match the decimal ones. Additonally, there's finite precision, so 0.9(20)'s nearest representable value is the same as for 1.0. Calling this behavior a "safety bug" may be a little far-fetched but indeed it may be confusing: n1 is in range and n2 is too (for user,not for CPU) but "both n1 and n2 in range" is false

Comment: Of course there's the question if 0.9(20) can be fully considered "correct (double) input" that the question refers to. It does parse, however - see some interesting discussion in docs for [Double.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with type safety and uncaught exception if the input somewhat happens to not be double. Then the code just throws an exception.

Comment: Well that's obvious enough, but that's more a matter of stability than safety? (of course depending on actual use).

Answer (score 0):

You can set x to 0, and you can enter 0 for y. But the values must be *between*.

You better use strictfp. 
You better use 0d instead of 0.

Comment: No. I can't. If set to 0 then it goes to false so that isn't the problem. (I'm using less nor less or equal for comparison).